# The SignalR's messageId value

Tags: asp.net, signalr, messageid

I use SignalR for my ASP.Net Application with longPolling protocol. I see that the client send the `\signalr\pool` request to server with the `messageId` form data: `d-B1017AFE-SC,B8|bW,0|bs,1|bx,2`.

I'm looking for the documents which describe the `d-B1017AFE-SC,B8|bW,0|bs,1|bx,2` format but not yet. Please help me to understand it. Below image was captured from Chrome Dev Toll which explains what I said.

[image]

My customer uses Azure WAF to protect the site. The Azure WAF report show that above request belong to the `Command Injection` risk because the `messageId` contain `|bw`,`|bs`, `|bx` that match the `|ps` rule in Azure WAF. So I need to understand the `messageId` content to explain for my customer and ask them customize the rule to ignore the request.

Below is the WAF description in the report:

> [{'riskGroup':'','match':'Vector Score: 5, Group Threshold: 4, Triggered Rules: 950006, Mitigated Rules: , Last Matched Message: System Command Injection','threshold':'4','type':'riskscore','version':'1','score':0,'atomics':[{'score':5,'riskGroup':'CMD-INJECTION-ANOMALY','**match**':'**|ps**','**ruleName**':'**System Command Injection**','**selector**':'**ARGS:messageId**','ruleId':'950006','version':'7'}],'actionId':'alert','ruleName':'CMD-INJECTION-ANOMALY','action':'Alert','selector':'','ruleId':'CMD-INJECTION-ANOMALY','category':'**Command Injection**'}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks right.  The `messageId` tells the server what was the last message the client received.  It looks something like this `d-3104A0A8-H,0%7CL,0%7CM,2%7CK,0` and Chrome is translating `%7C` to `|`.

[This](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/) document explains the SignalR protocol very well.

Internally, it looks to be based on the deserialized response.

Comment: I updated the post. The shared document does not explain the messageId in detail. Maybe it's for internal only.